# How do you add additional developers to be part of your AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

The following snippet is from AWS docs, if sharing credentials is not the right way. Does it involve additional charges for adding IAM to support multiple developers.

> Without IAM, if you want to enable other users to access your AWS
>   resources, the only way is to share your AWS account credentials. We
>   do not recommend this approach. Your account credentials enable access
>   to all AWS resources associated with your account, including your
>   billing information. For this reasons, we recommend that you never
>   share your AWS account credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no additional charge for IAM service. Please see following link: http://aws.amazon.com/iam/#pricing

To confirm it once again, you can check AWS monthly calculator at following link:
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html. I don't see any charges for IAM service at here as well.

Answer (score 0):

What that text is explain is that any user who has access to your account email login can change ANYTHING on your account. They could change your password and lock you out. There's no easy way to recover your account. A person from the billing department could accidentally or maliciously terminate your servers or delete S3 data. They're warning you that its not a good idea to give anyone but yourself access to the email login.

With IAM you can enable almost all the permissions that the email login has. The exceptions are changing the account credentials and personal information. Each user will be provided with their own username and password for access to the console and can be assigned a new set of Access Keys or x509 certificates if required.

There's no cost or downside to using IAM and its highly recommend for security reasons.